# VSCode から Spresense 関連のコマンドの実行ができない

Tags: spresense, vscode

下記の公式サイトに従い、Spresense 環境のセットアップを進めておりましたが、
VSCodeから「F1」キーでのコマンド実行でエラーが発生し、先に進めない状況です。

https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html

トラブル内容：
<kbd>F1</kbd> キーを押して「Spresense」に関するコマンドを実行してもエラーが表示されてしまいます。

```
コマンド'Spresense:MYSYS2のパス設定（Windowsのみ）'でエラー(command 'spresense.msys.path' not found)が発生しました
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

こんにちは。

私もSpresense VSCodeIDEや他の拡張機能でも `command ~~ is not found` というエラーを経験したことがあります。
私の場合拡張機能をインストールやアップデートしたときに発生していました。
VSCodeの再起動や拡張機能のアンインストール→インストールを行うことによってエラーが出なくなりましたので、お試しいただくと解消するかもしれません。

私は下記サイトを参考にしてみましたので、是非ご参照頂ければと思います。
[VsCode：command ‘code-runner.run’ not foundが表示されてCode Runnerが実行できないとき](https://dianxnao.com/vscode%EF%BC%9Acommand-code-runner-run-not-found%E3%81%8C%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6code-runner%E3%81%8C%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D/)